# Error en función jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Trabajo con html y jquery a la función le paso un número que es de tipo string y me devuelve el código de barras de acuerdo al número.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="js/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="barcode"></div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#barcode").barcode(
            "2001201901070202304500110011000000000161234567819",
            "code39"
        );
    });
</script>
</html>
```

El error es el siguiente.
[image: error código de barra]

Saludos!

Comment: Y el error es??

Comment: Tal como te respondieron te falta agregar tambien el js de barcode para que funcione

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que te falta instanciar la libreria `jquery-barcode.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="TuCarpeta/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TuCarpeta/jquery-barcode.js"></script>
```

Puedes descargarla de [aqui](https://barcode-coder.com/download/jquery-barcode-2.0.3.zip)

Comment: ¿Que es esto: js/jquery-latest.min.js? estuve investigando y nada, me imagino que es como poner jquery-3.1.1.min.js?

Comment: Así es, solo es la llamada de JQuery solo que debes tener en cuenta que primero debes poner la librería de JQuery y luego la del Barcode, que si las pones invertidas no funcionará

Comment: Excelente funciono thanks, otra pregunta lo que me da es una imagen si no me equivoco eso lo puedo poner en una ruta como: <td align="center">
                  <img src="@barcodeWeb" height="15" width="220">                  
                 </td>

Comment: El id o Clase a la cual le haces el selector es donde agregará la imagen del barcode, por ejemplo si quieres que lo agregue en el tag de img debes agregar un id o clase luego hacer el selector a ese id o clase por ejemplo `<img id="BarcodeIMG" height="15" width="220">` debes usar `$('#BarcodeIMG').barcode(... ` te recomiendo usar otro tag en lugar del img como el div es mas manejable en cuestiones de estilos